# Image doesn't stay in place (email marketing, using <td>)

Tags: html, email, html-table

I'm making a e-mail marketing using `<td>` and `<tr>`. Every image is in place, except for 2, the main ones. 
I tried to doesn't add display:block, tried to add it, tried a number of things, sliced the image in 2 etc, but this keeps happening.

I will add a image to better understanding:

[image: Here we can see that image on the right that is completely out of place]

What I'm doing wrong?

The code I'm using:

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:658px">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> <td style="display: block"></td><img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok">
        </td> <td> 
        <td style="display: block"></td> <img src="Images that are causing trouble"><img src="Images that are causing trouble"></td><br>
        <td> <td style="display: block"></td>
    <img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok"><img src="Images that are ok"></td>
            </tr>
```

EDIT: I fixed the problem, but now I'm having white spaces between each image, even when I'm using the "display: block". What should I do?

Comment: You have extra table markup in the first row. A data cell can't be a child of another cell.

Comment: You are nesting a TD inside another TD, that isn’t valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would erase `style="display: block"` from all `td`s – that's overwriting/anullating their table cell property, which is probably the main cause for your trouble (also, as stated in the comments, you shouldn't nest a `td` inside another `td`).

Comment: I'm using "display: block" because i'm doing it with multiple images, and I can't have the white spaces between them. There is another way to not have this problem?

Comment: well, but then you should apply `display: block` to the images, not to the table cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:658px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="Images that are ok"> 
                <img src="Images that are ok"> 
                <img src="Images that are ok"> 
                <img src="Images that are ok">
            </td> 

            <td>
                <img src="Images that are causing trouble">
                <img src="Images that are causing trouble">
            </td>
            <br>

            <td>
                <img src="Images that are ok"> 
                <img src="Images that are ok">
                <img src="Images that are ok">
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're using multiple `td`s within one `tr`. One tr is one row, and each `td` splits that row into another column. If you want the images to come one below the other, you need to use multiple rows.

Also, your code is not quite correct. You need to remove the nested `td`s within your `td`s. `br`s between `td`s are also a bad idea.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:658px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok">
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra TD markup nested in your code.

This should work:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:658px">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td style="display: block">
        <img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok">
    </td>
    <td style="display: block">
        <img src="Images that are causing trouble"><img src="Images that are causing trouble">
    </td>
    <td style="display: block">
        <img src="Images that are ok"> <img src="Images that are ok"><img src="Images that are ok">
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this code, but the white spaces between each image appeared again :( the "display: block" looks like isn't working now

Comment: Did you try once without "display: block" property?

Comment: Yes, it gets worse haha the images gets all over the page

Comment: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770 Refer this article, there are some nice tips to place images in an email template.